# Why does command-line completion not work for cc?.

Tags: ubuntu, cc

If I use the C compiler cc then command-line completion does not work. If I enter cc dig + press tab then nothing happens but if I compile the program with cc digenv.c then it works. Why no completion for the cc program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$ echo "complete -f cc" >> ~/.bashrc
```

and then source it to get the latest changes:

```
$ source ~/.bashrc
```

Then, try the completion.